# Redmine plugin: ajax "Uncaught ReferenceError: get is not defined "

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to figure out how to fix a problem with a plugin called "REdmine Hooks Manager" that I have just added to my Redmine installation.

Whenever I attempt to click on one of the buttons to configure the plugin Chrome Developer Tools reports:

Uncaught ReferenceError: get is not defined

The HTML that is generating the exception looks like this:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="$.ajax({url:'/hooks/tree?by=location', async:true, data:'hook=' + selected_hook + '&all=' + ($('show_all').checked ? 1 : 0), type:get}).done(function() {structured_by = 'location'})" class="">By location</a></li>'
```

and

```
<input id="show_all" name="show_all" onchange="$.ajax({url:'/hooks/tree', async:true, data:'hook=' + selected_hook + '&by=' + structured_by + '&all=' + ($('show_all').checked ? 1 : 0), type:get})" type="checkbox" value="1" />'
```

and

```
<a id="view_layouts_base_content" href="#" onclick="if ((html_code_changed == false) || confirm('HTML code has not been saved and going to be lost if you continue... Are you sure?')) { $.ajax({url:'/hooks/load?hook=view_layouts_base_content', async:true, type:get}).done(function() {updateSelectedHook('view_layouts_base_content')}); }" class="icon icon-file text-plain selected"> Content (bottom)</a>'
```

etc...

and I have located this javascript (that is being loaded) that seems to be related:

```
function updateSelectedHook(hook) {
  var previousItem = $('#'+selected_hook);
  if (previousItem) {
      previousItem.removeClass('selected');
  }
  selected_hook = hook;
  var nextItem = $('#'+selected_hook);
  if (nextItem) {
      nextItem.addClass('selected');
  }
  html_code_changed = false;
  }

function updateHookPreview() {
  $('#preview-content').html($('#html_code').val());
  $('#preview').show();
  }

function updateHooksTree(url, mode) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'get',
    data: 'hook=' + selected_hook + '&by=' + mode + '&all=' + ($('#show_all').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0),
    success: function(data) { structured_by = mode; }
  });
}

function updateHookForm(url, hook, msg) {
  if ((html_code_changed == false) || confirm(msg)) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        success: function(data) { updateSelectedHook(hook); }
    });
  }
}
```

The plugin works on a clean installation so I strongly suspect that it is a compatibility problem between 2 plugins.  After quite a bit of digging I have discovered that there seem to be 3 copies of jQuery being loaded.  Version 1.8.3, 1.7.1 and 1.7.3 so this may be causing the problem.

I've also tried to break into the updateSelectedHook function using the Chrome script debugger but it's not being called.  Perhaps because the $.ajax call itself is failing.

So... best guess right now is that a newer version of jQuery has changed the way that the ajax call is being made but I've run out of ideas regarding how to test further and hoped that someone here might be able to assist.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For sure you should include only one jQuery version. Now your issue is option `type` of ajax must be a string. As anyway GET type is used by default, just remove `type:get` option of your ajax requests (inline scripts). See DOC: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... I noticed that too when reviewing the documentation.  It specifies that type needs to be something like 'GET'.  I noticed both that it was a string and that it was in upper case.  So not I'm trying to figure out the ruby to see where the html is formed so that I can change or as you suggest, remove this parameter.  I've found come code which seems to be creating the line that I'm looking at... but I'm not familiar enough yet with ruby to properly decode it. So now looking for the function that it seems to call.

Comment: this is the ruby code: 

        onclick="<%= defined?(remote_function) ? remote_function(:url => { :action => 'load', :hook => hook }, :method => :get, :condition => "(html_code_changed == false) || confirm('#{l(:text_html_code_not_saved)}')", :complete =>  "updateSelectedHook('#{hook}')") :"updateHookForm('#{url_for(:action => 'load', :hook => hook, :format => 'js')}','#{hook}', '#{l(:text_html_code_not_saved)}')" %>"

Comment: I'm afraid, i don't know ruby

Comment: yea... me neither but I think that you have put me on the right track... thanks for that

Comment: well... I tried both hard coding the type:'GET' and removing it all together.  In both cases the exception goes away but the plugin does nothing.  I'll try reposting the question using the ruby and redmine tags.  Thanks again for the help.